# Handle multiple JavaFX buttons with one controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, event-handling

I'm trying to implement an MVC solution in JavaFX like I used to with swing. It seems to me that there are some differences. My usual approach was to have a `Starter class` to initialize a `view` and `model` and pass them both to the `controller` with the constructor. I would then give the `view` a reference to the `controller` so it can registrate it for the UI handling. I then would use `setActionCommand("xy");` on any GUI element I need to access in the `controller`. `setActionCommand();` ist not available for JavaFX. I've also seen posts that I should use different controller for different elements, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409044/javafx-multiple-buttons-to-same-handler).
I started implementing it as I'm used to and I'm now stuck at the point where I can't assign a method to a button. My 3 buttons look like this:

```
Button newGraph = new Button("Neuer Graph");
newGraph.setOnAction(controller);
Button extendGraph = new Button("Graph erweitern");
extendGraph.setOnAction(controller);
Button reset = new Button("Filter zurücksetzen");
reset.setOnAction(controller);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class GraphController implements EventHandler {
    private GraphHandler graphHandler; //model
    private GraphView graphView; //view

    public GraphController(GraphHandler graphHandler, GraphView graphView, Stage stage){
        this.graphHandler = graphHandler;
        this.graphView = graphView;
        graphView.registerController(this); //introduce controller to view
        graphView.start(stage); //start the main frame
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSource().toString());
    }
}
```

Which does print:

```
Button@1f74b31a[styleClass=button]'Filter zurücksetzen'
Button@37901011[styleClass=button]'Neuer Graph'
Button@39afc158[styleClass=button]'Graph erweitern'
```

How can I distinguish the buttons without using `if(event.getSource().toString().equals("Button@1f74b31a[styleClass=button]'Filter zurücksetzen'"));` or somthing the like?
I'm also looking forward to use it on `CheckBox` and `MenuItem`.

Edit:
Partly solved it by parsing the `sender` to a button.

```
@Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        try {
            Button sender = (Button) event.getSource();
            switch (sender.getText()){
                case "Filter zurücksetzen":
                    System.out.println("reset");
                    break;
                case "Neuer Graph":
                    System.out.println("new");
                    break;
                case "Graph erweitern":
                    System.out.println("extend");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there a more generic way? Since I don't want to parse the other events as well, which would result in more `try, catch` blocks. Altough this might be a question for `codereview` at that point..

Comment: The usual way is simply to use different handlers for each control. Is there some reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: I don't want my application to be full of `controller` classes and still use an `mvc patter`, but as mentioned, I don't know yet how to do this properly in JavaFX.

Comment: Well you don't necessarily have to have different classes for every one, but just use different instances. Or just use lambda expressions (see hostz's answer) to minimize the code overhead (or anonymous inner classes, though those are verbose compared to lambdas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX relies heavily on the use of lambdas. In the case were the event handler is simple (only a few lines of code) and not reused by any other controls, you can do it like this:

```
Button reset = new Button("Filter zurücksetzen");
reset.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Clicked on 'Filter zurücksetzen'"));
```

If the same simple lambda expression is reused you can define it separatly and reuse it:

```
EventHanlder handler = event -> System.out.println("Clicked on 'Filter zurücksetzen'");
Button reset = new Button("Filter zurücksetzen");
reset.setOnAction(handler);
```

Or if you want to have them defined in you Controller you can do that as well without the need for the Controller to implement `EventHandler`:

```
public void handleClickOnReset(Event event) {
    System.out.println("Clicked on 'Filter zurücksetzen'");
}
```

And then use it like this:
reset.setOnAction(controller::handleClickOnReset)

Comment: Sounds well, I'll give it a try :) I'll mark it if it works out

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to use a different handler for each control. Typically this is done with lambda expressions, as in hotzst's answer; if you prefer a more legacy approach you could also just add one or more parameters to your stand alone class and use different instances of it.

```
public class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final String message ;

    public ButtonHandler(String message) {
        this.message = message ;
    }

    @Override
    public handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

and then

```
Button newGraph = new Button("Neuer Graph");
newGraph.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler("New"));
Button extendGraph = new Button("Graph erweitern");
extendGraph.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler("extend"));
Button reset = new Button("Filter zurücksetzen");
reset.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler("reset"));
```